# How to remove bottom shadow for navigationBar in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I tried to set with empty image, but it not working

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting background image & shadow images working for me. Thanks @xingou

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what the API document said :

> The default value is nil, which corresponds to the default shadow image. When non-nil, this property represents a custom shadow image to show instead of the default.   **To show a custom shadow image, you must also set a custom background image with the setBackgroundImage(_:for:) method. If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image is used regardless of the value of this property.**

so you need set the backgroundimage first.